# Jupyter Notebook networkx tex node font too small

Tags: networkx, tex, jupyter-notebook

I've written some code to display a bipartite graph using networkx in a jupyter notebook.  I've rendered the labels of the nodes using what I assume is Tex.  However I, cannot seem to get the size of the rendered Tex font to increase.  Is there a simple way of doing this?  Help would be great.

Below is my code and an image of the bipartite graph,
[image: bipartite graph]

```
import networkx as nx
% matplotlib inline
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(['$x_1$','$x_2$','$x_3$'], s='o', c='#AA5555', bipartite=0) # Add the node attribute 'bipartite'
B.add_nodes_from(['$f_a$','$f_b$','$f_c$','$f_d$'], s='s', c='#55AAAA', bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([('$x_1$','$f_a$'),('$x_1$','$f_b$'),('$x_2$','$f_a$'),('$x_2$','$f_b$'),('$x_2$','$f_c$'),('$x_3$','$f_c$'),('$x_3$','$f_d$')])

pos = dict()
X, Y = bipartite.sets(B)
pos.update((n, (i,1)) for i, n in enumerate(X))
pos.update((n, (i+0.5,2)) for i, n in enumerate(Y))

disjointSetCount = 2
for disjointSet in range(0, disjointSetCount):
    nx.draw(
        B, 
        pos, 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_shape = 's' if disjointSet == 1 else 'o', 
        node_color = '#FFEEEE' if disjointSet==1 else '#EEEEFF', 
        node_size=1000, 
        nodelist = [
            sNode[0] for sNode in filter(lambda x: x[1]["bipartite"]==disjointSet, B.nodes(data=True))
        ]
    )

plt.savefig("img/15_Graphical_Models_12b.png") # save as png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the optional arguments for `nx.draw` is `font_size`.  If I set `font_size=100` I get

[image]

That should be plenty big.

Comment: Wow, that is might big!